# How to divide possibly big numbers in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, progress, division

My question concerns a script I'm writing to automatically back up several Folders and subfolders with a batch file.
Now I'm trying to implement some kind of progress indicator in a readable format, preferably in per cent.
First of all, it reads the total size to copy with the following command:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\XXX" %%F IN (*.*) DO (
set /a overall=!overall!+%%~zF
)
```

For the specific folder in my testing batch, this returns a size of 266,173,879 Bytes.
However, if I try to divide this number by, say, 1024 (for Kilobytes) after the for-loop with

```
set /a overall=%overall%/1024
```

the Batch returns something along the lines of "/1024 can not be used here syntactically" (You probably know the correct translation, mine is in German).
I tried adding/removing parantheses and spaces, but I keep getting the same error.

Is there something wrong with my syntax, which I'm too blindfolded to see?
If not, how do you call a C++ .exe delivering the value of %overall% to be assigned to a C++ variable?
(C++ is the only other programming language I have minimal to basic knowledge of, PowerShell is not an option, it has to be regular Windows Batch)

complete code of relevance:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\XXX" %%F IN (*.*) DO (
set /a overall=!overall!+%%~zF
)

set /a overall=%overall%/1024

FOR /R "C:\Users\XXX" %%F IN (*.*) DO (
xcopy "%%F" "E:%%~pF" %parameter%>nul
cls
echo Copying... Progress: !size! of !overall! KB copied.
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some good info about Batch files and their math limitations.  The page also has some information on how to best deal with these limitations.

> There is a severe limitation in batch math: it can only handle 32-bit integers.
>   **[`http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)**

Which is **4,294,967,295** for unsigned, **−2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647** for signed.

---

For simplicity, you may just want to look into using **[`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)** if you are using Windows 2003/XP or newer.  Note that you must install the **[Windows Resource Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)** (Works on XP) to add the robocopy tool.  See the robocopy link for all the features and logging options.

Comment: `robocopy` is a good tip, but the 32-bit limitation isn't the issue here.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I agree. Hence why I have the max values for a 32bit int.  I put that in to specifically show that the size was not the issue and to try and entice the OP to go to the link which has much more information. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how batch handles numbers, but I think using C++ would be a better choice, as you can use an `int`, `long` etc, for whatever number you need.

You can pass your numbers to your C++ app using

```
yourcpp.exe !overall! 1024
```

and pick them up using `main`'s arguments and divide them (my C++ isn't great, but something like this should do)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
double n = (double)argv[0]/(double)argv[1];
return 0;
}
```

Then you can store it how you want, maybe [output to a text file](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/), which you can read using the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the expression has a syntax error. The number you are trying to device is 260 million, which is safely within the maximum precision of 32 bits numbers that batch can handle.

I think the problem is that the value is actually `266,173,879`, including the commas. Depending on your localisation settings, the division may fail over those characters.

If I try `266,173,879/1024`, it always returns `0`, which is not good.
If I try `266.173.879/1024`, it says 'missing operator', which in't right either.

Another possibility is that `%overall%` hasn't got a value the first time. That makes the expression look like

```
set /a overall=/1024
```

That is, of course, invalid and returns the error `missing operand`, which is slightly different from `missing operator` mentioned above.

If think the safest thing is to make sure that %overall% has a value first, and try to remove the commas from the string next.

After that it should work:

```
C:\>set /a overall=266173879/1024
259935
```

Note that you will get in trouble when your directory is larger than 2 GB.